# Access private property successfully in the same file but failed to use private inner class in swift

Tags: swift, access-control

Here is my code:

```
public class TestPublic{
    internal class TestInternal{
        private class TestPrivate{
            private var x = 123
        }
        func foo()
        {
            print(TestPrivate().x)
        }
    }
}

let x = TestPublic()                        
let y = TestPublic.TestInternal()           
let z = TestPublic.TestInternal.TestPrivate() // This trigger an access error!!!
y.foo() // After removing last line.Everything compiles well and output '123'
```

The guide book of swift 2.0 said:

> “Private access restricts the use of an entity to its own defining source file. Use private access to hide the implementation details of a specific piece of functionality.”

Now I wrote all these codes inside one single file.

`TestPrivate.x`should be visible to `TestInternal.foo`.And this is ok for now.

But the wired thing is when I try to use the private inner class to create an instance it failed compiling! Is this a bug?

Comment: What compiler error did you get?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug.

```
private let z = TestPublic.TestInternal.TestPrivate()
```

This would make it compile.

Without `private` indicator `z` can expose private class to other files for its access control is `internal` by default.

And this is how swift control accesses strictly.